# Не работают наушники

Tags: аудио, ubuntu

Доброго времени суток! На kubuntu 12.04 не работают наушники, хотя на динамик звук идет. Как понять в чем проблема? Ноут hp dv-6.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/339924/why-do-the-headphones-not-work-on-my-hp-pavilion-dv6

Comment: не помогло

Comment: alsamixer тоже не помогло ? модуль перегружали ?добавьте в вопрос вывод    lspci    lsmod |grep snd    amixer -c 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alsamixer смотрите внимательно! Часто проблема кроется в какой-нибудь не включенной галочке...

Comment: И действительно.

Answer (score 0):

На наушники выход не от того источника. Там в настройках покопаться надо!